# jquery load inside a jquery ui tab only sometimes or when I select a new tab

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery ui tabs with four tabs, each tab displays a table with some data and all the table are more or less the same.
Inside the tab before the table I have two link to change the table order.
All run fine and I can change the order if:
- I select a tab for the first time after page refresh
- I select the tab 4, then the tab 3 then the tab 2

after this only tab 2 run always correctly
tab 3 and 4 don't change
but if I select a different tab I see the content loaded and then the new tab

this is the js code for tabs and sorting:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html("Error");
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs("option", "active", 0);
    $("div.ui-tabs-panel").delegate("#sorter a.sort", "click", function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    var e = $(this), d = $("#sorter").parent("div");
        d.load(e.attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the tab content loaded:

```
<div id="sorter">
    <a class="sort" href="/it/private/ajax/proposals/region/latest">latest</a>
    <a class="sort on" href="/it/private/ajax/proposals/region/voted">voted</a>
</div>
<table class="zebra">
<tr><td>....</td></tr>
</table>
```

thank you
Paolo